# Chain a function to a string to be printed

Tags: javascript

I want to print a string, e.g. `blah` 3 times, but I want to chain the function to that string.

I now do it like so:

```
function repeatMe( number ) {
     for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            document.write('blah');
     }
}

console.log( repeatMe( 3 ) );
```

But would it be possible to call the function to print `blah` like so:

```
console.log( 'blah'.repeatMe( 3 ) );
```

Comment: Notice that `repeatMe` should *return a string*, not print it. The function is not called `printMeTimes` or so. You want to call it like `document.write(repeatMe('blah', 3))`, *or* `console.log` it, or…

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a concatenated string by adding `repeatMe` to the string prototype:

```
String.prototype.repeatMe = function (number) {
  var txt = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    txt += this;
  }
  return txt;
}

var div = document.querySelector('#id');
div.innerHTML = 'blah'.repeatMe(3);
```

Or:

```
console.log('blah'.repeatMe(3));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rjf3sqos/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you just have to add it to the String type:

```
String.prototype.repeatMe = function (number) {
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    document.write(this);
  }
};

"blah".repeatMe(4);
```

Comment: Thanks, How would I make it so that it shows blahblahblah in the console, instead of printing to the document? I replaced document.write(this) with return this but that did not work.

Comment: you could just add a line inside the for loop that says ```console.log(this);```

Comment: If I do that, and then call the function via console.log, I get the contents of the string object instead of blahblahblah being printed.

Comment: No. You concatenate the string inside the function and return that instead. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this by adding to the String prototype chain. Since `"blah"` is a string, you'll want to add this to the prototype chain for strings.

Solution:

```
String.prototype.repeatMe = function ( number ) {
     for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            document.write(this);
     }
}

console.log( 'blah'.repeatMe( 3 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple version to repeat a string: use an `Array` and join with the string

To repeat function execution: see snippet code

```js
String.prototype.repeat = function (n) { return Array(n + 1).join(this); };
Function.prototype.repeat = function (n) {
  n -= 1; 
  if (n > 0) { this(); return this.repeat(n); }
  return this();
};

var result = document.querySelector('#result');
var bar = function () { result.innerHTML += '<br>bar' };
result.innerHTML = 'foo'.repeat(5);
bar.repeat(5);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```